# UK Tier 5 visa - does AIESEC-UK contribute in the salary of the person sponsored?

Tags: united-kingdom

I've learned recently that the UK government offers Tier 5 visas for students wishing to stay in the UK for a period of 12 months, to do internships or to work for a short period of time. These Tier 5 visas are usually sponsored by AIESEC-UK.

Knowing that AIESEC-UK is paid by the employer, I was wondering whether AIESEC-UK contribute in the salary of the trainee/worker? in other terms what's its actual role in this case (is it like TLSContact and VFS Global, i.e. just an intermediary)?

Sorry if this is not the right forum to ask this question.